# Remove user permission from content after creation

Tags: 7, users

We have a business case where it is needed to remove user permission for a specific content type after submission.

Think of it something like submitting an application.

If there is better workflow suited than removing user permission, please let me know.

Comment: Each content type has different permissions set allow user View/Create/Edit/Delete. in order to allow the user only create the application you need to give him a create permission, and after creation, he won't be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking because you only want a user to be able to create 1 (and only 1) node of a specific type? Or (as Ziftman suggests) do you just want to prevent the person the person from editing content after they have created it? If its the former, you could do something like this:

Create a custom module with a hook_form_alter that checks if the user has created content of that type and, if so, hide the form or redirect or whatever. D7 code below, but similar works for D8) Ex:

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  global $user;

  // do a query to find out if the user has created a node of this type before
  $already_created = db_query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM {node} WHERE type='application' and uid=%uid", array('%uid' => $user->uid))->;

  if ($already_created->count) {
    $form['#access'] = FALSE;
    drupal_set_message("You cant do this");
    drupal_goto('some/other/path');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this one. This looks like better approach than Ziftman's in regard to our case.